# Edit an entry and then delete it

Tags: postgresql

I try to edit a postgresql entry and immediately delete it. The goal is that the field to be updated is used as a trigger parameter that logs the operation.

If I use a stored function, everything is working correctly. But if I use CTE I can not delete the record.

```
with tmp as (
   update users set by_user_id = '0004' where id = '0006' returning id
)
delete from users
using tmp
where users.id = tmp.id;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/b677a/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the documentation:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)

> Trying to update the same row twice in a single statement is not supported. Only one of the modifications takes place, but it is not easy (and sometimes not possible) to reliably predict which one. This also applies to deleting a row that was already updated in the same statement: only the update is performed.